# scenepic library / change opacity of background

Tags: python, opacity

I am trying to use scenepic for some 3D animation. (It is some pendulum). When it swings to the 'background, the parts in the background disappear. I assume that the opacity of the background is too high - **but how can I change it?**
Thanks a lot for any help!